# TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>) when using jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

The testing code:

```
import { rule } from  '../../../../src/core/linter-rules/check-charset.js';

describe("Core Linter Rule - 'check-charset'", () => {
  const ruleName = "check-charset";
  const config = {
    lint: { [ruleName]: true },
  };

  test("checks if meta[charset] is set to utf-8", async () => {
    const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("test doc");
    doc.head.innerHTML = `
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>ReSpec</title>
    `;

    const results = await rule.lint(config, doc);
    expect(results.length).toBe(0);
  });

  test("doesn't give an error when written in capitals", async () => {
    const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("test doc");
    doc.head.innerHTML = `
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>ReSpec</title>
    `;

    const results = await rule.lint(config, doc);
    expect(results.length).toBe(0);
  });

  test("checks if meta[charset] is present or not", async () => {
    const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("test doc");
    doc.head.innerHTML = `
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>ReSpec</title>
    `;

    const results = await rule.lint(config, doc);
    expect(results.occurrences).toBe(0);
  });

  test("returns error when more then one meta[charset] present", async () => {
    const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("test doc");
    doc.head.innerHTML = `
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta charset="ascii-128">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>ReSpec</title>
    `;

    const results = await rule.lint(config, doc);
    expect(results.occurrences).toBe(2);
  });

  test("return error when some other charset defined", async () => {
    const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("test doc");
    doc.head.innerHTML = `
      <meta charset="ascii-128">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>ReSpec</title>
    `;

    const results = await rule.lint(config, doc);
    expect(results.occurrences).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

`check-charset.js`:

```
/*
 * Linter Rule "check-charset".
 *
 * Checks whether the document has `<meta charset="utf-8">` properly.
 */
import LinterRule from "../LinterRule";
import { lang as defaultLang } from "../l10n";

const name = "check-charset";
const meta = {
  en: {
    description: `Document must only contain one \`<meta>\` tag with charset set to 'utf-8'`,
    howToFix: `Add this line in your document \`<head>\` section - \`<meta charset="utf-8">\` or set charset to "utf-8" if not set already.`,
  },
};

// Fall back to english, if language is missing
const lang = defaultLang in meta ? defaultLang : "en";

/*
 * Runs Linter Rule.
 *
 * @param {Object} conf The ReSpec config.
 * @param {Document} doc The document to be checked.
 */
function linterFunction(conf, doc) {
  const metas = doc.querySelectorAll("meta[charset]");
  const val = [];
  for (const meta of metas) {
    val.push(
      meta
        .getAttribute("charset")
        .trim()
        .toLowerCase()
    );
  }
  const utfExists = val.includes("utf-8");

  // only a single meta[charset] and is set to utf-8, correct case
  if (utfExists && metas.length === 1) {
    return [];
  }
  // if more than one meta[charset] tag defined along with utf-8
  // or
  // no meta[charset] present in the document
  return {
    name,
    occurrences: metas.length,
    ...meta[lang],
  };
}
export const rule = new LinterRule(name, linterFunction);
```

I am trying to integrate `jest` into my node.js project, initially the tests were written in `jasmine` I use `jest-codemods` to convert the jasmine tests into jest !

But, when I run the tests `npm test` I get these weird errors.

I get this error saying : 
`TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)`

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9qK.png)

What does it exactly mean ? I searched a lot on the net, couldn't find any satisfying explanation anywhere!

Plus  it's strange why it's showing me an error in the part of the code which has comments!

Comment: defineProperty expects the first parameter to be an object. Pass a non-object value to it and you get that error. That's not really a "weird" error! https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) We can't help you with code we can't see. Reduce the problem to a [mcve] that you can share (along the way, you'll probably find the problem). Fundamentally: You're passing a non-object as the first argument to `defineProperty`. You can't do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added a code snippet!

Comment: @undefined I don't really get what a `non-object` value is ...

Comment: @undefined is it weird in the place it shows the error, it highlighting the comments in the screenshot I put as the location of error!

Comment: @GaganGanapathy A value which is not an object is simply called a non-object. Regarding the error, when an external library is used, sometimes you get an error which is not related to your own codebase. Possible reasons: Either you are not using the library APIs correctly or the library itself has a bug! You need to trace the error.